Custom uikit library, how to create a good reusable modal component with createPortal()
actually i'm working on a custom uikit library for React, and i wrote a lot of reusable component.
Now i want to create a good reusable Modal component, that must be rendered always on top of all elements, so i decided to use createPortal(). but now i have a few questions...
1: how can i create the div for portal (that should be inside index.html on a react app)?
2: can i do this in my library or must be manually created by the app owner?
Actually my (UNCOMPLETED) component looks like:
import React, {
    FC,
    MutableRefObject,
    useEffect,
    useRef,
} from 'react';
import {
    RVModalContainer,
    RVModalOverlay,
} from './styled';
import { RVModalProps } from './types';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

const modalRoot = document.getElementById('modal-root');

const Modal: FC<RVModalProps> = ({ show, close }) => {
    const contentRef: MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | null> = useRef(null);

    if (!show) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <>
            {createPortal(
                <RVModalOverlay>
                    <RVModalContainer
                        ref={contentRef}
                    >
                        example uncompleted text
                    </RVModalContainer>
                </RVModalOverlay>,
                modalRoot,
            )}
        </>
    );
};

export default Modal;


It'll be good if someone can explein me what is the best way to achieve the best re-usable result.
P.s. my library is made with storybook, rollupjs, typescript and styled components.
I've tried to create the modal-root div inside the component, but actually doesn't work and i can't see the result in storybook (the modal not appear and the modal-root div is not appended into the body.
what i've tried
const Modal: FC<RVModalProps> = ({ show, children }) => {
    
    const modalRoot = document.createElement('div');

    useEffect(() => {
     
        modalRoot.id = 'modal-root';
        document.body.appendChild(modalRoot);

        
        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(modalRoot);
        };
    }, [modalRoot]);

    if (!show) return null;

    return createPortal(
        <RVModalOverlay>
            {children}
        </RVModalOverlay>,
        modalRoot 
    );
};

export default Modal;

